Tag search only lets me type the first letter on mobile
When I try to add a tag to a post, I can only type one letter, and then the keyboard immediately closes and the textbox is deselected. Re-selecting the textbox adds a one-letter tag to the post which I can't edit to add more letters, only delete.
If the desired tag isn't found when searching by the first letter, I can't then use it to tag a post due to this bug.
OS: Android 14 (GrapheneOS)
Device: Google Pixel 6a
Browser: Vanadium 128.0.6613.88

You're using a non supported browser. Use a standard browser like Chrome and you'll enjoy all features of Stack Exchange. This is NOT a bug.

@Starship try installing the browser OP is using and most likely you'll be able to "repro" the behavior. It's not related to OS or device.
